# List providers, imports, declarations programmatically in an Angular 4...8 component

Tags: angular, jasmine

Is there a way to programmatically list the imports, declaration and providers that are in-scope in a component by some means of reflection for the purpose of configuring a TestBed in an Angular (Jasmine) test.

Comment: At times I've encountered indirect dependencies of component which needs to be provided and configured in TestBed, so I'm not sure what are you asking is possible.

Comment: Maybe there's an array of providers that can be compared before and after the component loads? Anybody knows where Angular keeps that stuff?

Comment: Ok, seems possible : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pERhnBBae2k

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but this might do it : https://indepth.dev/hooking-into-the-angular-bootstrap-process/